# Streaming data via Bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm looking at using Bookshelf.js as an ORM for an Express project, with Knex. My only question is whether it supports streaming--if we have a query which returns many results, I'd prefer to deal with a stream rather than saving the results in memory. I am not seeing this functionality in the docs, but perhaps there's a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Bookshelf doesn't have that functionality, but you can use Knex directly which does. Of course you lose the benefits of using an ORM, but you gain a bit more performance in return, which is probably more important if you're dealing with huge amounts of data.

You can read more about it in [Knex's documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Streams).